# Zuul Route Definition

Tags: routes, netflix-zuul, hystrix, contextpath

I am having a small issue in getting the Zuul route config correct. Here's what I have currently

```
 zuul:
  routes:
    microservice:
      path: /service/*
      serviceId: session
      sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorization
microservice:
  ribbon:
    listOfServers: localhost:8090
```

At the Microservice i have a Restcontroller like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service")
```

I have multiple end points in the RestController, for example:

```
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET}, value = "/service1", produces = "application/json")
```

Now when I send a request like `localhost:8080/service/service1` it does not hit the expected endpoint. It routes the request to `localhost:8090/service1` (where nothing is running).

It works well if I change the context path like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service")
```

to

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
```

I have tried changing the path from
      path: /service/*
to

```
path: /service/**
```

but no effect.

The other option is to force the routing at the filter level, but I think it should be possible to route `localhost:8080/service/service1` to the microservice directly. Any suggestions on how I can get this done in the Zuul configuration.

I cannot use the URL option since it is not compatible with the fallback that I am working with.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get it done is by stopping the prefix stripping; looks like it is enabled by default.

```
path: /service/**
stripPrefix: false
```

Answer (score 0):

The routing key is not intended to be the part of the target url.
For example, /service/** path will use the expression to route requests to the mapped service with the path mentioned after the expression which is "/service1". If the routing key is required as part of the target url too, stripPrefix needs to be be set to false.